# mysql database connectivity in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

i am developing a small web application in asp.net and using mysql as backend. so for doing database connectivity for mysql database, i have downloaded 'MySql.Data.dll' and added as reference in project. so my question is that Is ther any changes which i have to made in 'web.config' ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use MySql Connector. [MySqlCOnnector.](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) and Demo. [MYSQL Connection](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/355977/Csharp-ASP-NET-MySQL-Connection-Tutorial-with-MySQ)

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection mycon = 
  new MySqlConnection("YourConnectionStringHere);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to connect to the database you could do something like this:

```
using (MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection("connection string here"))
{
    c.Open();

    // and now let's select some data
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SomeTable", c);

    MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        // do something with the fields here
    }
}
```

and then if you wanted to execute an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statement do something like this:

```
using (MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection("connection string here"))
{
    c.Open();

    // and now let's select some data
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE SomeTable SET Field1 = 'some value' WHERE some where clause", c);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

and please [leverage the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples.html) to get you the rest of the way because I have no idea what else you're trying to do. From that link there you can get to the `MySqlCommand` and other classes.

Finally, you need to read up on parameterized queries because this statement for example, `UPDATE SomeTable SET Field1 = 'some value' WHERE some where clause`, really should be something like `UPDATE SomeTable SET Field1 = @Field1 WHERE some where clause` and then parameters set on the command like this:

```
cmd.AddWithValue("@Field1", "some value");
```

and if there were any static values in the `WHERE` clause the same applies.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following imports for MySQl

using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

1.Create the new website in visual Studio and save it

2.Now open the Default.aspx form and drag some Labels, text boxes and button.

```
<asp: Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br/> <br/><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Address"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp: Textbox> <br /> <br /><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Age"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp: Textbox> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
```

4.Now For Creating the Connection you will need this

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page

{
MySqlConnection con;
MySqlCommand cmd;
string str;
}
```

5.Now In Page_load event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
con = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Database=YourDatabase Name;User ID=root;Password=YourPasssword");
con.Open();
Response.Write("connect");
}
```

6.Now write the code on button_click event

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
str = "insert into YourTablename values ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "')";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(str, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

You can Find this Helpfull too....with this link 
 http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/brij_mcn/mysql-database-connectivity-with-Asp-Net/

Answer (score 0):

```
<% 
'declare the variables 
Dim Connection
Dim ConnectionString
Dim Recordset
Dim SQL

'declare the SQL statement that will query the database
SQL = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME"

'define the connection string, specify database driver
ConnString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=Your_Mysql_DB; " &_
"UID=mysql_username;PASSWORD=mysql_password; OPTION=3"

'create an instance of the ADO connection and recordset objects
Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'Open the connection to the database
Connection.Open ConnString

'Open the recordset object executing the SQL statement and return records 
Recordset.Open SQL,Connection

'first of all determine whether there are any records 
If Recordset.EOF Then 
Response.Write("No records returned.") 
Else 
'if there are records then loop through the fields 
Do While NOT Recordset.Eof   
Response.write Recordset("FIRST_FIELD_NAME")
Response.write Recordset("SECOND_FIELD_NAME")
Response.write Recordset("THIRD_FIELD_NAME")
Response.write "<br>"    
Recordset.MoveNext     
Loop
End If

'close the connection and recordset objects freeing up resources
Recordset.Close
Set Recordset=nothing
Connection.Close
Set Connection=nothing
%>
```

from http://webcheatsheet.com/ASP/database_connection_to_MySQL.php

Comment: If we're writing in .NET let's leverage the built-in classes. They are optimized far past `ADODB`, and further these objects are unmanaged resources that are much harder to clean up.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow simple instructions [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL).

You have to download the library for database connection. Just follow the steps in the link.

Enjoy.